# How to load composer package from remote git when running in production, and load from local package when development environment?

Tags: php, composer-php

I have two composer files to run composer in each environment

```json
"repositories": [
        {
            "type": "vcs",
            "url": "https://github.com/igorhaf/laravel-admin"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.2.5|^8.0",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.4",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^7.4",
        "laravel/framework": "^7.0",
        "laravel/telescope": "^3.0",
        "laravel/tinker": "^2.5",
        "encore/laravel-admin": "dev-master"
    },
```

I want running laravel-admin from a local folder in my project (packages) when I am using  local environment, but with the same `composer.json` file

Comment: You cannot. Why are you trying to do that instead of always using same type ?

Comment: @matiaslauriti
 because if I use remote approach in develop, I should commit and push all package changes and should run composer update to update my vendor code, and if use local approach in production, I should keep a local code development in my production server

Comment: Never, EVER, have a local code when you can have it on a package on other repository. So, if you are on production, always do the normal `composer update`, to update your package, but when working on development, you will still have to do the same, still, if you want to "modify" the package, you should have the package in another repository and all your package's code there. Can you tell me what is the idea of your package and if you know how to develop a Laravel Package ?

Comment: composer install generates a composer.lock to always get the same version of packages next time. You can't have a different `composer.json` in production without also having a different `composer.lock`. This can be done by changing the [`COMPOSER`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer) environment variable. Now having an indentical composer.json between local and production and only differ in a single part is not possible without some code that manipulates these files

Comment: @matiaslauriti I think he can and I have posted an answer below to that effect. Most probable you have not used such approach before. I have developed a lot of Laravel Packages in Private repositories using same method below for a long time and never had issues.  Also there will be no need to change your composer file or even create separate environments.

Comment: Try this https://github.com/SanderSander/composer-link

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your use case clearly, you develop custom Laravel package and you don't want to always have to push it before you test it in local.

There's absolutely a use case for it. I personally use it. With this approach, your composer.json can stay the same both on local and server. No need to change anything.

1. You would need the package https://github.com/franzliedke/studio . The documentation is quite explanatory. You install it globally via composer. `composer global require franzl/studio` though can be installed per project but that's quite tedious because you may only need it locally.
2. At the root of your project run `studio load path/to/your/local/vendor/directory/*` (if you want all packages in directory) or `studio load path/to/your/local/package` (for a single package. You may add multiple packages). This will generate a studio.json file at the root.

Eg.

```json
{
    "version": 2,
    "paths": [
        "path/to/local/vendor/directory/*",
        "path/to/local/package"
    ]
}
```

3. Anytime you run `composer update`, composer will first look in your studio.json file and symlink to local packages if available, else get it from the remote repository.

**Note:**
i. Make sure to add `studio.json` to `.gitignore`.
ii. Also remove the paths from studio.json as seen below and run `composer update` to generate new `composer.lock` file before you push your code to production/server. Else your code on server will be looking for packages from the symlink in local setup when you run `composer install` and give you errors.

```json
{
    "version": 2,
    "paths": [
        
    ]
}
```

iii. After pushing to server, return the studio.json to initial state and continue to develop. No need to push to github/remote vcs before you see your changes. Changes are symlinked from local if available or gotten from remote.

iv. Run `composer install` on server.

v. Don't forget to push your package to remote else, you will not see the changes on server, though you see on local.

Comment: No sir, this is not a right approach, if you want to develop Laravel Packages, stick to the right way, use [`orchestra/testbench`](https://github.com/orchestral/testbench), even the creator of Laravel uses it on his Laravel Packages, do not try to make ugly things or reinvent the wheel, this is not a right approach, if you want to test or develop a package, develop it separate from the Laravel framework, as you cannot share it, if you don't want to share it, then it is not a package...

Comment: You can look at official Laravel Packages and all of them (and other not official packages) uses this. [Fortify](https://github.com/laravel/fortify/blob/1.x/composer.json#L25), [Passport](https://github.com/laravel/passport/blob/10.x/composer.json#L37), [Horizon](https://github.com/laravel/horizon/blob/5.x/composer.json#L27), even other packages like [Laravel IDE Helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper/blob/master/composer.json#L40). Don't use this approach as it is not a good thing...

Comment: @matiaslauriti are you sure you know what the question is talking about at all? Composer is not used only in Laravel applications. My answer will work for all PHP applications using composer and not just Laravel. I know what Laravel test bench is, however the use case will not always be right. Also in coding it is not right to force your coding dogma on another developer when you do not know the use case. Even developers of various applications realise sometimes that there may be better ways of doing things which may have escaped them initially, that's why they accept pull requests.

Comment: Quoting @matiaslauriti - "develop it separate from the Laravel framework, as you cannot share it, if you don't want to share it, then it is not a package...". There is a difference between `open source` and `closed source` packages. The fact that a company or an individual uses Laravel (Open Source) does not mean that all packages developed should be posted in public repos even when the use case is specific to that business. I will suggest you desist from making authoritative statements such as "you cannot", "you are wrong", "it's impossible" as if there's only one way of doing something.

Comment: Current way (my way) is the normal way for Laravel Developers, STICK TO IT, do not try to reinvent the wheel. And the author is asking for Laravel... I am not going to have a discussion with you about this as the author did not even share the use case, but still, if you use GIT, you will see changes on the history related to the package... that should be exclusive to the package itself... do what you want, horrible or beautiful code... stick to what it is the standard right now, and I have already shared what the standard is... do not reinvent the wheel and in a bad way... period.

Comment: Alright @matiaslauriti I think you should post your answer since you claim to  "KNOW THE RIGHT WAY" of doing it. No need to discuss with me. It will go a long way to help instead of trying to tell in comments how wrong it's being done. Post a full answer with references (if possible). I believe the author will be grateful. I would even love to see alternatives.

Comment: Huh. I didn't know about "studio". I find that the idea could be overkill for most cases (I just add the a `repositories` entry on my dev machine to point the package to my local repo, but it's true it not impossible to "forget" to remove those changes). Nice to know about a new tool, and with a decent answer at that. This other user seems to be confused about the question, the comments are completely misguided.

Comment: @yivi thank you for the kind response. Yes you are right. In most cases it will be an overkill especially when developing a single package which you could easily edit your composer file when need. In my use case, I was developing multiple packages closely linked and I didn't want to go through the trouble of having to change repositories anytime I changed something. It also helps not to mess up the composer.json for other people when working with a team in case you forget to change the repositories back to the previous state.

Comment: I made a composer plugin for this https://github.com/SanderSander/composer-link because of studio wasn't exactly useful for me. It doesn't require any configuration file, and doesn't edit composer.lock or composer.json file.

Comment: @SanderVisser your package seems like a very nice approach to go about it. I like the fact that it doesn't update the lock file. I will give it a try and maybe help to review it. I will add it to the answer after trying it out. Also when you want use the production packages, do you just unlink the linked packages and run composer update?

Comment: @ibmgeniuz When you want to use the production package, you can just run `composer unlink` and you're done, no need to run `composer update` the unlink command will download the package defined in the .lock file